# Difference between gradient and Jacobian in gradient descent

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

What is the difference between the computation of gradient (the partial derivative of error w.r.t. weight) in gradient descent and the computation of the Jacobian in Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

The "Jacobian" in this context is the Jacobian matrix of the gradient, which is the Hessian of the underlying objective function. It is therefore quite a bit more expensive to compute than the gradient (because you need $O(n^2)$ numerical second derivatives instead of $O(n)$ numerical first derivatives).

Comment: Can you please elaborate it mathematically. If the error is expressed as the mean square error wrt some weight w. Then how will we compute Jacobian

Comment: @user6460588 The Jacobian of what? The Jacobian you need in Levenberg-Marquardt is the Hessian of the error function (which is a sum of squared residuals). In principle this could be analytically computed, but in practice you just compute it using a numerical differentiation routine.

Comment: Yes so can you express that mathematically. Taking example if y1 is the predicted value and y is the actual value. The error or the residual will be (y1-y).^2 sum over some m values. Then what will be the jacobian

Comment: @user6460588 The Hessian is $H_{jk}=\frac{\partial^2 \sum_{i=1}^n (y^{(1)}_i-y_i)^2}{\partial y_j \partial_k}$.

Comment: what is j and k

Comment: @user6460588 The indices of the entry of $H$, ranging from $1$ to $n$.